# What are the actual effects of Quality?

Tags: life-is-feudal

The [wiki](http://lifeisfeudal.gamepedia.com/Life_is_Feudal_Wiki) and several interviews and promo pieces I've found say

> Quality is measured on a scale from 1 to 100 and ultimately effect all
>   actions that are performed with a usage of that item: crafting,
>   resource gathering and even combat.

That's pretty generic.  I haven't found anything listing the actual effect quality has on a given item.  Does quality of weapons affect their damage?  What is quality of building material used in a house or wall do?  Etc.

I think it would be good to make a list of what quality actually affects for the different aspects of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, from in-game testing and what I can gather from the wiki, I have:

---

Food Quality

- affects the amount of hunger recovered from eating it
- affects skill multiplier

---

Tree Quality

- affects the amount of resources (twigs, sprouts, boards, etc.) that can be harvested from it.
- affects quality of resources harvested

---

Tool Quality

- affects the number of hitpoints a tool has - that is, how many times you can use the tool before it breaks.
- affects the quality of materials produced by recycling it
- typically (but not always) affects the quality of good produced while using the tool (ex. Higher quality knife produces higher quality handles - see wiki for exact cases)

---

Weapon Quality

- affects the number of hitpoints a weapon has - that is, how many times you can hit someone with it before it breaks
- affects the quality of materials produced by recycling it
- affects the damage dealt with a successful attack

---

Armor Quality

- affects the number of hitpoints a piece of armor has - that is, how many times it has to be hit before it breaks.
- affects the quality of materials produced by recycling it

---

Device Quality

- affects the quality of final products produced with that device - that is, a higher quality forge will create higher quality tools.
- affects the hitpoints of the structure (how hard it is to destroy by siege and/or decay)